# Example of a topological space that satisfies the first countability axiom but not the second one

Tags: general-topology

I am a beginner in topology and am struggling in writing down examples of topological spaces besides from the most trivial ones and some common metric spaces. I need a rather simple example of a topological space that satisfies the first axiom of countability but where the second one does not hold. I thought about the simple Euclidean metric in $R^1$ but it seems to me that this does have a countable base and therefore must satisfy the FAC. What could be an example?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think such a space exists?

Comment: @Mathias Barreto Your title and the question in the body don't match. Please clarify which is your actual question.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: The Euclidean metric on the reals is both first and second countable, indeed. But there are non-separable metric spaces too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\Bbb R$ in the discrete metric/topology.

Or consider the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology), e.g.

Or the lexicographically ordered square. Many exist.

Answer (score 0):

Second countable implies first countable.

The converse is not true: take an uncountable discrete space.